# An irrational puzzle

Tags: mathematics, visual

**What's the answer to this puzzle?**

---

[image]

Comment: May I ask is the third symbol in the bottom line a triangle ($\triangle$) or capital delta ($\Delta$)? Also, is the fifth symbol a degree symbol or just a small 0? Thanks!

Comment: @CheeseCake Yes, it's a triangle

Comment: It's a degree symbol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Prem's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/118242/57156) (+1) pretty much nailed it except that

> the S.t. and picture with an X through it means such that it is not on the line connecting the red dots.

Then a

> triangle with an angle more than 90 degrees is accomplished by any dot that is to the left of 1/4 or to the right of 3/4 or any dot within a circle of radius 1/4 centered on the center
>  [image]

So the

> probability is 0.5 + 0.196 = 0.696

Comment: Well done! This is the right interpretation and the answer is correct.

Comment: Nice [ +1 ] I agree that the "X" is "negation" , not "Diagonal Intersection" ! Observation : there is no Irrationality involved & the title was not a clue !

Comment: Why does the arrow for the yellow dot have some sort of flip indicator above it? Do we know what that means?

Comment: @Prem the rot13(nern bs gur pvepyr / cv) is irrational

Comment: @Amoz good question, i dunno. that is actually where I got stuck the first time i looked at this puzzle

Answer (score 4):

What I got till now :

> Take 2 red Dots or Points. Put those into the Square.

> Each Dot must be 1/4 Distance from the vertical sides.

> Each Dot must be 1/2 Distance from the top side.

> Take a yellow Dot & put it into the Square.

> Such that , It is on the line joining the 2 red Dots where the Diagonal lines are shown to intersect this line at the Centre.

> What is the Probability that the Angle in the triangle is more than 90 ?

> Might be Irrational , involving PI or trigonometry.

Comment: Good job (+1), you had the right idea except for the lower part of the puzzle. A correct answer has been given by Cap

Comment: Oh ok , (1) I thought that It was the Diagonal Intersection , not a negation (2) I thought that there must be Irrational Probability. Either ways, Nice Puzzle !